# Hangman System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: vb.net

i am creating a hangman game that is to be used on a few computers, i have created the hangman game itself but i am using the "load form" function to create the list when the program first starts, but i am having this issue.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'h:\Bryson\words.txt' because it is being used by another process.

```
Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("h:\Bryson\words.txt")
```

^^that line is where the error pops up^^

I have inserted some in code Comments to make life easier. If anyone can help thanks in advance :)

```
'USED TO CREATE HANGMAN FILE IF NOT FOUND
    Private Sub main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    fofound = False
    fifound = False
    MsgBox("remove this and change file path and fix qu2 quiz")
    'DESIGNER USE
    Dim path As String = "h:\Bryson\words.txt"
    'CREATE VAR FOR PATH
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists("h:\Bryson") Then
        'CHECKS IF FOLDER EXISTS
        fofound = True
    Else
        'IF IT DOES THEN IT MOVES ON
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("h:\Bryson")
        'IF NOT IT CREATES THE FOLDER
        fofound = True
        If File.Exists("h:\Bryson\test\words.txt") Then
            'CHECKS IF FILE EXISTS 
            fifound = True
        Else
            'IF IT DOES IT MOVES ON
            IO.File.Create("h:\Bryson\words.txt")
            'IF NOT IT CREATES IT
            FileClose()


        End If

    End If
    If fofound And fifound = True Then
    Else
        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("h:\Bryson\words.txt")
            'CRASH POINT The process cannot access the file 'C:\Bryson\words.txt'
            'because it Is being used by another process.
            sw.WriteLine("Hangman")
            sw.WriteLine("computer")
            sw.WriteLine("electrode")
            sw.WriteLine("independent")
            sw.WriteLine("stream")
            sw.WriteLine("enforcing")
        End Using
        'WRITES TO FILE
        MsgBox("file created")
        'DESIGNER USE
        FileClose()
        'CLOSES FILE
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just ran your code and it seems to work. However check if you have a `drive H: ` which I think you don't and fix your path. It should be something like `C:\Bryson\words.txt` instead of `h:\Bryson\words.txt`

Comment: @3vts yes there is a H drive, i have confirmed that. All my documents are on the H drive

Comment: Your variable `fifound`will _never_ be true.  You only check for the existence of the file when you create the new folder.  Since you just created the new folder, there is no chance that a file could be there so `fifound` will always be false.  Also, having an empty If block is a code smell.  I would remove the `Else` and change the If to `If Not (fofound AndAlso fifound) Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileClose()` is a legacy function from VB6 and will not affect anything in the `System.IO` namespace. To close a file you need to call `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` on the stream that has opened the file (wrapping the stream in a `Using` block does this automatically).

Your problem is this line:

```
IO.File.Create("h:\Bryson\words.txt")
```

The method creates a new file and opens a `FileStream` to it which locks the file. Since you never close the returned `FileStream` your file will remain locked until you close your application.

The `File.Create()` call is completely unnecessary though because `File.CreateText()` will create the file if it doesn't exist. So you should just remove the above line.